# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:“Access denied for user 'hobo'@'49.70.207.34' (using password: YES)”

Tags: c#, mysql, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.1

I want to use EntityFramework Core for configuration and operational data for IdentityServer4.I used Mysql.An error occurred while executing the following code.The code is `"serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();"`
The error is

```
MySql.Data. MySqlClient. MySqlException: 'Access denied for user 'seen' @ '49.70.207.34' (using password: YES)' error.
```

But I had no idea where the address 49.70.207.34 came from, in the database connection string I configured is another address;My connection string is `'server=47......;database=IdentityServer4.Configuration;user=hobo;password=123456'.`

Comment: 49.70.207.34 is the IP Address of the PC/device that is trying to access the database on the server with IP Address 47......  You need to ensure that user 'hobo' is configured on the MySQL server to be allowed access from IP Address 49.70.207.34

Comment: Thank you very much!With your help, I found the cause of the error and solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

### **You can Try this method**

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

```
Public cn As New MySqlConnection()

Public Sub openconnection()
    If cn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        cn.ConnectionString = "Server=website.com; Database=YourDatabaseName; Uid=YourUsername; Pwd=YourPassword"
        cn.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub closeconnection()
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).